# Converting child to screen space in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

currently I have 2 images, ImageA and ImageB.
ImageB is a child of ImageA

Assuming ImageA position is in (100, 100);
then ImageB local position is (10, 0);

So what I'm trying to do is how can I retrieve the screen position of ImageB whereby it will return me (110, 100) instead of (10, 0)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API to get world position of sprite.

```
    CGPoint loc =[self convertToWorldSpace:sprite.position];
```

Comment: I did tried that but doesn't work for me.
End up I have to use
ImageA.position + ImageB.position

Comment: what results did you receive and where did you call this method?

Comment: CGPoint loc =[parentNode convertToWorldSpace:child.position];